# Debugging memory allocation with glibc-2.22

Tags: memory-leaks, glibc, memory-leak-detector

I am working on a custom embedded Linux distribution, libc is glibc-2.22.

How to track memory allocations/frees for an application while the application runs in automation for long duration. Are there hooks in glibc that will generate logs each time an allocation/free happens in my application?

Answer (score 0):

> Are there hooks in glibc that will generate logs each time an allocation/free happens in my application?

No. Writing to log on every allocation would be

- too expensive (a high performance malloc can allocate memory in a few 10s of instructions and without any system calls)
- mostly useless: usually you don't just want to know that 2000 bytes where allocated; you also want to know where they were allocated from, and that is definitely too slow to perform on every allocation in a production application.

Your requirements are not unique: e.g. Google runs applications for many days, and developers often want to know how much memory is being consumed by which parts (when you run 100s of 1000s of applications, a wasted MB here and there quickly adds up).

To this end, tcmalloc comes with [heap profiler](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/heap_profiler.html), which can answer many of above questions. So does [jemalloc](https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/wiki/Use-Case:-Heap-Profiling) as well.

Comment: Glibc mtrace does log every allocation as text to file https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libc/manual/html_node/Allocation-Debugging.html https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Tracing-malloc.html, and https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/MallocTracing from dj/malloc branch does tracing of all allocations into binary file.

Comment: PS: is tcmalloc still used by corporations? It looks like not updated for long times, and global allocation lock for huge allocations still not changed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a glibc branch with a high-performance allocation tracer:

- https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=shortlog;h=refs/heads/dj/malloc

It's still a bit rough, but it has been used with some degree of success with multi-threaded, allocation-intense workloads.